# Call plpgsql function in select's where clause

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a plpgsql function `complementwhere(parameter1 date)`  which returns a complex where clause as a text, let's say it returns `clause2 = filter2` just as an example, but it actually returns a bunch of other clauses.

I need to call this function in a select's where clause to complement that clause, this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE clause1 = filter1 AND complementwhere(parameter1);
```

But this returns the error

> argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You can try to pass whole row to your function and change it so it will return boolean that indicates if row matches your complex where clause. See this http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/Store-Procedure-Function/Passinawholerow.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert a text *value* into *code*, which is not normally possible in SQL. You need to either do two round trips to the server.

1. Fetch `WHERE` clause: `SELECT complementwhere('<mydate>')`.
2. Build the query based on the first and execute it: `SELECT .. WHERE ...`.

**Or** (preferably) use dynamic SQL with [**`EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a single PL/pgSQL function. There are many examples here on SO, [try a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D+%5Bdynamic-sql%5D+EXECUTE).

You didn't provide your actual code ...

Be wary of ***SQL injection*** whenever you turn user input into code.